# Converting EBNF to BNF

Tags: language-agnostic, computer-science, bnf, ebnf, recursive-descent

It's been a few years since my computer-language class and so I've forgotten the finer points of BNF's and EBNF's and I don't have a textbook next to me. Specifically, I've forgotten how to convert an EBNF into BNF.

From what little I remember, I know that one of the main points is to convert

```
{ term }
```

into

```
<term> | <many-terms>
```

But I don't remember the other rules. I've tried to look this up online but I can only find links to either homework questions, or a small comment about converting terms with curly braces. I can't find an exhaustive list of rules that define the translation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

See [this page](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/archive/compilation-ssc/2000/part4/parsing/node3.html). It contains instructions for each production that needs to be converted:

> From EBNF to BNF
>
> ---
>
> For building parsers (especially bottom-up) a BNF grammar is often better, than EBNF. But it's easy to convert an EBNF Grammar to BNF:
>
> - Convert every repetition `{ E }` to a fresh non-terminal `X` and add
>
>   ```
>   X = ε | X E.
>   ```
> - Convert every option `[ E ]` to a fresh non-terminal `X` and add
>
>   ```
>   X = ε | E.
>   ```
>
>   (We can convert `X = A [ E ] B.` to `X = A E B | A B.`)
> - Convert every group `( E )` to a fresh non-terminal `X` and add
>
>   ```
>   X = E.
>   ```
> - We can even do away with alternatives by having several productions with the same non-terminal.
>
>   `X = E | E'.` becomes `X = E. X = E'.`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I need. Someone I never found that link!

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on that link now... any idea if there is an updated version somewhere?

Comment: Alas, not off the top of my head. Hopefully the page will come back.

Comment: The page has moved to http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/archive/compilation-ssc/2000/part4/parsing/node3.html

Answer (score 1):

Be warned: EBNF as it's listed in the ISO standard also includes exceptions to syntactic rules, which do not have a BNF equivalent. The conversion given by 500 - Internal Server Error only works for the portion of EBNF which overlaps with RBNF/ABNF.