# How to correctly translate BNF to GoldParser?

Tags: bnf, gold-parser

Say I have this in BNF:

```
a ::= b {c}
    | d {e}
```

Is there any way to translate to Gold-Parser? Without breaking it up like this:

```
<a> ::= <b> <c>

<c> ::= 
    | <c> terminal
```

Side Note: If anybody has a better title/more tags, please edit it, thanks!

Comment: By BNF you mean EBNF? (see bottom of http://goldparser.org/articles/bnf.htm)

Comment: I've seen it. About ebnf vs bnf, or teacher said that there isn't a precise name for them, since they are variants, and similar to each other

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to translate to Gold-Parser? Without breaking it up

No, it doesn't support the repetition operator (`{x}`) as part of [rule definitions](http://goldparser.org/doc/grammars/), so you must encode it with multiple rules.

See also [Converting EBNF to BNF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2466484/319698)