# I want to convert EBNF to BNF

Tags: bnf, ebnf

EBNF

```
<A> ::= <B><C> '('[<D>{,<D>}]')';
```

When I solve the problem, it comes out like this:

BNF

`<A>::=<B><C>(); |<B><C> (<D>|<A><D>);`

Is the answer correct?

Comment: Your EBNF doesn't look correct. EBNF generally drops the angle brackets around non-terminals because terminal symbols are enclosed in quotes. Also, you don't enclose the one instance of a comma in quotes. In some EBNF, comma is the concatenation operator. If you intended for it to be a concatenation, then you don't apply it consistently in the rest of the rule. I suspect it a literal. So, shouldn't your EBNF rule be `A ::= B C '(' [ D { ',' D } ] ')' ;`? We can't answer your question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It contains instructions for each production that needs to be converted:

**From EBNF to BNF**

For building parsers (especially bottom-up) a BNF grammar is often better, than EBNF. But it's easy to convert an EBNF Grammar to BNF:

- Convert every repetition { E } to a fresh non-terminal X and add X =

  ```
  $\epsilon$ | X E.
  ```
- Convert every option [ E ] to a fresh non-terminal
  X and add

  ```
  X = $\epsilon$ | E. (We can convert X = A [ E ] B. to X = A
  E B | A B.)
  ```
- Convert every group ( E ) to a fresh non-terminal X and
  add `X = E.`
- We can even do away with alternatives by having several
  productions with the same non-terminal.

  ```
  X = E | E'. becomes X = E. X
  = E'.
  ```

Refer this links:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466484/converting-ebnf-to-bnf)
- [Link 2](http://lampwww.epfl.ch/teaching/archive/compilation-ssc/2000/part4/parsing/node3.html)