# Converting W3C's EBNF to BNF

Tags: bnf, ebnf, recursive-descent

Following up on
[Converting EBNF to BNF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466484/converting-ebnf-to-bnf/), which has a rule of:

> ### From EBNF to BNF
>
> For building parsers (especially bottom-up) a BNF grammar is often better, than EBNF. But it's easy to convert an EBNF Grammar to BNF:
>
> - Convert every repetition `{ E }` to a fresh non-terminal `X` and add
>
>   ```
>   X = ε | X E
>   ```
> - Convert every option `[ E ]` to a fresh non-terminal `X` and add
>
>   ```
>   X = ε | E
>   ```
>
>   (We can convert `X = A [ E ] B.` to `X = A E B | A B.`)
> - Convert every group `( E )` to a fresh non-terminal `X` and add
>
>   ```
>   X = E
>   ```

but the question is on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/)'s EBNF notation, whose definition can be found at https://www.bottlecaps.de/rr/ui, which has a different notation:

`Item ::= Primary ( '?' | '*' | '+' )*`

I can understand both cases, but applying them to real examples is where I'm stuck.

E.g., for,

`Y ::= A E+ B`

I believe that translate to:

`Y = A { E } B`

And the corresponding BNF notation would be the following right?

```
Y = A X B
X = ε | X E
```

Now, this is the real question that I'm not sure:

`(Item ( '-' Item | Item* ))?`

I believe that translate to:

`Items = [Item ( '-' Item | {Item} )]`

And would the corresponding BNF notation be the following?

```
Items
  = Item
  | Items ItemsApp
  | ε

ItemsApp
  = '-' Item
  | Item
  | ε
```

And moving further, for

```
Choice
 ::= SequenceOrDifference ( '|' SequenceOrDifference )*

SequenceOrDifference
 ::= (Item ( '-' Item | Item* ))?
```

Is the `| Item*` part really necessary? Would the above be equivalent to the following?

```
Choice
 ::= SequenceOrDifference ( '|' SequenceOrDifference )*

SequenceOrDifference
 ::= Item ( '-' Item )?
```

(given that normally there won't be any BNF definition that has an empty RHS in real world)

Comment: Be careful in your transformations from one notation to another. Note difference with `*` and `+` operators: `Y ::= A E+ B` => `Y = A (E | { E }) B`. Do not drop stating LHS of a production `Items ::= (Item ( '-' Item | Item* ))?` == `Items = [Item ( '-' Item | {Item} )]`. `SequenceOrDifference ::= (Item ( '-' Item | Item* ))?`. "Is the | Item* part really necessary?" YES! "Would the above be equivalent to the following?" NO! Watch your transformations. `SequenceOrDifference` could derive empty string. You have it after refactoring deriving `Item` minimally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @kaby76, as for the last point, ***if*** BNF definition does not allow empty RHS, would my transformation be equivalent _then_?

Comment: Yes, BNF--as defined by the Algol60 group--does not have empty alts or rules. So, there is no direct equivalent for `Items ::= (Item ( '-' Item | Item* ))?` because `Items` derives empty (it has '?' op at the outer grouping on RHS). So, your BNF for `Items` and `ItemsApp` are incorrect.  Note, the "BNF" notation used here and the other SO question isn't "BNF" per se because meta symbols must have '<' and '>' surrounding the name, and use '::=' not '='. People need to read "Revised report on the algorithmic language ALGOL 60".